# Would my implementation of this enum pass?

Tags: enum, kotlin

I have a feature with feature flagging enabled, basis the condition I want to load different pages in my screen, to achieve this I have the following enum:

```
enum class ImageHolderEnum(
    val titleId: Int,
    val qFragment: BaseFragment,
    val fragment: BaseFragment
) : IPageHolder {
    PAGE1(R.string.tab_shop_baby, BabyTwoFragment(), BabyThreeFragment()) {
        override fun getTitle(): Int = titleId
        override fun getFragmentToAdd(): BaseFragment =
            if (isFeatureAllowed()) qFragment else fragment
    },
    PAGE2(R.string.tab_shop_mom, MomThreeFragment(), MomTwoFragment()) {
        override fun getTitle(): Int = titleId
        override fun getFragmentToAdd(): BaseFragment =
            if (isFeatureAllowed()) qFragment else fragment
    },
    PAGE3(R.string.tab_shop_dad, DadTwoFragment(), DadThreeFragment()) {
        override fun getTitle(): Int = titleId
        override fun getFragmentToAdd(): BaseFragment =
            if (isFeatureAllowed()) qFragment else fragment
    };

    fun isFeatureAllowed(): Boolean  {
        val qSlideConfig: QSlideConfig by remoteFeatureFlag() // Kind of dependency injection here 
        return qSlideConfig.isQSlideEnabled()
    }
}
```

The interface is as follows:

```
interface IPageHolder {
    fun getTitle(): Int
    fun getFragmentToAdd(): BaseFragment
}
```

I am concerned if I am using the dependency injection inside the enum and breaking some principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you giving seperate implementations for each enum value? All `getTitle()` and `getFragmentToAdd()` implementations are the same.

```
enum class ImageHolderEnum(
    val titleId: Int,
    val qFragment: BaseFragment,
    val fragment: BaseFragment
) : IPageHolder {
    PAGE1(R.string.tab_shop_baby, BabyTwoFragment(), BabyThreeFragment()),
    PAGE2(R.string.tab_shop_mom, MomThreeFragment(), MomTwoFragment()),
    PAGE3(R.string.tab_shop_dad, DadTwoFragment(), DadThreeFragment()),
    ;

    override fun getTitle(): Int = titleId
    override fun getFragmentToAdd(): BaseFragment = if (isFeatureAllowed()) qFragment else fragment

    fun isFeatureAllowed(): Boolean  {
        val qSlideConfig: QSlideConfig by remoteFeatureFlag() // Kind of dependency injection here 
        return qSlideConfig.isQSlideEnabled()
    }
}
```

Interfaces can also have properties, so there's no need to have `getTitle()` as a function, when it can just be a value.

```
interface IPageHolder {
    val titleId: Int
    fun getFragmentToAdd(): BaseFragment
}
```

And you can then use it like this in the enum class:

```
enum class ImageHolderEnum(
    override val titleId: Int,
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware if I could do that, this looks much cleaner!